# Unity3D plugins multiple MAIN activities in Android manifest file

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, manifest, prime31

I have Unity3D project with multiple plugins in it. I use TapJoy, Prime31, Facebook, Native and other plugins. All of them needs to have MAIN activity in Android manifest file. SInce that is not possible i started searching for solutions.

After long research i found out that i can subclass needed java activity class and make it MAIN instead, from it, i should call super method to instantiate my needed super class. (Same answer found in many forums).

My question is: How will i be able to make all plugins "MAIN" by subclassing only one and making it MAIN activity? How can i make all activities initialise as if they were MAIN? Maybe i can do that in C# without defining my own subclass?

Any help would be awesome. This issue has been a headache for days now.

Comment: AFAIK if you start an Activity, the rest of the Activities paused. So even if you would have created a manager class to start / stop different Activities, they would probably interfere with each other. People should stop creating UnityPlayerActivity based plugins, and go this - http://eppz.eu/blog/unity-android-plugin-tutorial-1/ - way.